# Why is it better to use an additional CSS class to replace the H5 class?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a class for H5 that I am using on my site. There are instances where I am using the same style in a table. I was using `<th><h5>Header name in the style of h5 class</h5></td>` and have since learned that I should not nest h5 or any other h element  inside of a `<th>`. So instead I plan to create a class, let's say "h5StyleHeader" to apply to the `<td>` achieve the same styling. This doesn't seem right to me, is there something I am missing?

I am trading off 1 H5 class when using
 `<td><h5>text</h5></td>`

In favor of having to create 2 classes which do the same exact thing and getting:

`<td class="h5StyleHeader">text</td>`

Where is the benefit in this?

Comment: `h5` is a block-level element. While it may not be illegal, putting block-level elements inside of table cells and headers often means you're improperly using tables for layout instead of for data. And semantically, it's not clear what the `h5` is a header *for*, since it only applies to one column of the table. Better to use a class, as you are now, which is defined in the same place as the `h5` styles.

Comment: @Blazemonger I am not using it for layout I am actually styling the the text at the top of the table rows for my table of data.

Comment: Then use a class. It's more semantically correct, and it's trivial to define `h5, .h5 {...}` in your CSS at the same time.

Comment: @Blazemonger Good call thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real benefit.

The convention of not nesting h tags inside table cells is merely convention, similar to how you don't nest divs inside spans. (At least that's what I hear from many people)

An interesting point though:
Search engines that index sites look for specific tags such as header and nav, and possibly h tags. These tags all help search engines figure out how your site's structure works. Don't quote me on that though, I'm not 100% sure on the h tags being indexed.

Of course if you're not using the h5 tag as a header, and merely as styling, then stick with a class.

Comment: well, divs inside spans isn't just convention; it's technically illegal html. (the browsers generally cope with it, but you'll get an error if you validate it)

Comment: [This table](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1) is useful for seeing what types of children are valid in a given element. A `<td>` can accept "flow" elements, which includes both `<div>` and `<h5>` (plus the other `<hX>` elements). A `<span>` can only accept "phrasing" content, of which `<div>` is not a part. So putting `<h5>` inside of `<td>` is entirely valid. Putting `<h5>` inside of `<th>`, OTOH, may not be allowed, as the linked table indicates that `<th>`'s children rules are more complicated than simply allowing "flow" content.